# hide mouse cursor over specific client area in windows

Tags: c++, windows, cursor, directx, hide

I have directx embedded into a child window of my application and would like to hide the windows cursor only when it's over that client area. I know how to hide the cursor in general and did manage to find a make-shift example if only showing the cursor while it's not over any client areas, but it wasn't helpful for this.
How can I hide the cursor only while it's over a specific client area (/child window)?

edit:
this is as close as I've gotten but the cursor flickers unpredictably (as the mouse moves) while over the dx area

```
case WM_SETCURSOR:
{
    static bool bCursorVisible = TRUE;

    if( hWnd!=hwD3DArea && !bCursorVisible )
    {
        ShowCursor((bCursorVisible=TRUE));
    }
    else if( hWnd==hwD3DArea && bCursorVisible )
    {
        ShowCursor((bCursorVisible=FALSE));
        return TRUE;
    }
}
break;
```

edit2:
AHAH!
you have to use wParam instead of hWnd in this message
Here's the working code:

```
case WM_SETCURSOR:
{
    static bool bCursorVisible = TRUE;

    if( ((HWND)wParam)!=hwD3DArea && !bCursorVisible )
    {
        ShowCursor((bCursorVisible=TRUE));
    }
    else if( ((HWND)wParam)==hwD3DArea && bCursorVisible )
    {
        ShowCursor((bCursorVisible=FALSE));
        return TRUE;
    }
}
break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fix:

```
case WM_SETCURSOR:
        {
            static bool bCursorVisible = TRUE;
            if( ((HWND)wParam)!=hwD3DArea && !bCursorVisible )
            {
                ShowCursor((bCursorVisible=TRUE));
            }
            else if( ((HWND)wParam)==hwD3DArea && bCursorVisible )
            {
                ShowCursor((bCursorVisible=FALSE));
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
        break;
```

I was on the right track but was using hWnd when I should have been using wParam (which holds the REAL handle of the window the cursor is in)

Answer (score 2):

```
case WM_SETCURSOR:
{
    if (LOWORD(lParam) == HTCLIENT)
    {
        SetCursor(NULL);
        return TRUE;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Please explain why this would help.

Comment: This test addresses the question of the "actual client area".
When writing a windowed DX app, it's a common mistake to always hide the cursor, which makes it extremely hard to resize, move or close the window (as you don't see the cursor).

Calling DefWindowProc directly is just my way of making sure the default window proc gets called (as it is it that will handle the cursor change in those move/size/close cases)

Comment: I added a test to see if the next WM_SETCURSOR was HTCLIENT again so that we don't spam SetCursor(NULL) over and over. Works great. Thanks Jérôme!

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be simpler if you just set the cursor for that specific client window to a null cursor.

Comment: that doesn't work because it seems to draw an spinny thing instead then overwrites it with a pointer if you roll out and then back in. (that was the first thing I tried.) I found a solution though. Will add info asap.