# How to detect mouse hovering in a non-client section of a window?

Tags: winapi, mouse

I have a program that paints to the client area about 60hz using Direct3D 9, and the mouse is interfering, so I want to get rid of it **only** when it moves across the client area.

I thought that calling `ShowCursor(false)` in `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and calling `ShowCursor(true)` when `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE` is called by the system would work, but it results in a poor behavior.

So I found that `TrackMouseEvent()` would make the job, but I'm calling it in the following way:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static bool g_fMouseTracking = false;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        if (!g_fMouseTracking)
        {
            TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
            tme.cbSize = sizeof(tme);
            tme.dwFlags = TME_NONCLIENT;
            tme.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;
            tme.hwndTrack = hWnd;
            g_fMouseTracking = TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
         }
     break;
     case WM_NCMOUSEHOVER:
         ShowCursor(true);
         break;
    ...
```

and `WM_NCMOUSEHOVER` is never called. I don't know why.

Anyway, this is only one piece of code, to do what I want I know I need more code, but if it's not calling `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE` I can't start doing more advanced mouse hovering tricks.

Comment: You should call TrackMouseEvent after the window is created.  Non Client mouse messages always occur before any normal client mouse messages

Comment: No way, i called it after window created and no effect. Do i have to call TrackMouseEvent() only once?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28347885/1889329) is probably what you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: "*the mouse is interfering*" - in what way, exactly? Makes me feel like this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) and you should be focusing on the core issue rather than hiding the mouse as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to track `WM_NCMOUSEHOVER` you must use `TrackMouseEvent` in `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE`.